# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'icons.map') React-Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to render a series of icons from an array, `icons`, but when I try to return `{icons.map((icon, index) =>(<Icon key = {index} icon={icon}/>))}`, I get "typeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'icons.map')".

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
const BottomTabs = ({ icons }) => {
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab]  = useState('Home')

    const Icon = ({icon}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => setActiveTab(icon.name)}>
            <Image source = {icon.inactive} style= {styles.icon}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )

    return (
        <View>
            { icons.map((icon, index) =>(
                <Icon key = {index} icon={icon}/>
            ))}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

EDIT:
This is how my array is being passed through the component:

`<BottomTabs icons = {bottomTabIcons}/>`

And this is an example of what the objects in the array itself looks like:

```
const bottomTabIcons = [
    {
        name: 'Home',
        active: require('../../assets/home-active.png'),
        inactive: require('../../assets/home.png') 
    }
]
```

Am I passing the array through my `BottomTabs` component incorrectly?

Comment: Aren't you referencing icons in its very definition?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm confused about the error @BenjaminW.

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding, you can't use something to define itself.

Comment: What is icons?  I know it's an array of icons but what does that look like? Might be wrong type?

Comment: How do you use the `BottomTabs` component?

Comment: just edited the post to include how the ```BottomTabs``` component is being used @mbojko @ColinHale

Answer (score 1):

You did not pass `icons` to the `BottomTabs` component. Check if you pass icons correctly when calling `<BottomTabs icons={icons}>`